# How to setup the Azure Active Directory autentication to a single page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I'm using OWIN combined with Azure Active Directory App Registration as my authentication method on my MVC Web App as below to restrict the login user within a single domain. This part is functioning well.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

    string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Home/ErrorPage?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Now I want to use another Azure Active Directory App Registration to restrict few users to only one admin configuration page. I don`t know if it doable and how to do it.

This is current controller attribute code to redirect user to a username/password login page before accessing admin configuration page. How can I change it to be redirected to an AAD login. In this way, I can configure the qualified user in AAD without maintain any username and password.

```
public class ConfigLoginAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public bool Ignore = true;
    public ConfigLoginAttribute(bool ignore = true)
    {
        Ignore = ignore;
    }
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Ignore == false)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (CookieHelper.GetCookie("username") == "")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("Default", new RouteValueDictionary { { "Action", "AdminLogin" }, { "Controller", "Config" } });
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

I`m new to this area and even English. Hopefully I explained it clear.
Thank you guys so much in advance.

Comment: Why not just assign some group/role to the required users in Azure Active Directory and check against that?

Comment: I cannot find a way to check the user against AAD for a single page, all the code reference is for the entire app.